# Abrir archivo KML generado en python, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo una funcion la cual genera un archivo KML, esta funcion esta asignada al boton generar.

Lo que necesito es que al dar click en el boton generar, genere el archivo pero tambien lo abra en google earth.

```
def generar():
    
    kml = simplekml.Kml()
    kml.newpoint(name="coordenadas", coords=[(longitud,latitud)])
    kml.save("\\utm.kml")
    if latitud and longitud != "":
        messagebox.showinfo("showinfo", "Archivo KML Generado correctamente")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("showinfo", "El archivo no se genero.")
```

**Boton que genera archivo kml**

```
 #boton generar kml
    convert_button1 = ttk.Button(root, text='Generar KML')
    convert_button1.grid(column=2, row=10)
    convert_button1.configure(command=generar)
```

Comment: Si el archivo tiene un programa predeterminado con el que se puede abrir, te recomiendo mirar las respuestas a esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679798/how-to-open-a-file-with-the-standard-application Quizás sea mejor idea usar el programa predeterminado que abrirlo con google earth

Comment: con webbrowser pude realizar lo que necesitaba, no se si es la mejor opción, pero funciono para mi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre abrir el archivo utilizando **webbrowser**, no se si es la mejor opción pero funciono para mi.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new_tab(filename)
```